# Date isn't getting parsed

Tags: java, date

```
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
            java.util.Date date = null;
             date = sdf.parse(request.getParameter("cdate"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Mistake in syntax  change your new SimpleDateFormat(**"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss**") to new SimpleDateFormat("**yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss**")..

```
 System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2015-04-12 23:59:59"));
```

and your request.getParameter("cdate") string must be in same format i.e. "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: I did as you said but somehow I still get problem and show error  as                           java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/05/2016"

Comment: you must have to give date in format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.  your date it must be i.e. 2016-05-01 00:00:00

Comment: I did it but somehow not get parse date.

Comment: if your incoming date in format of 01/05/2016 you must have to use.
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/05/2016")

Comment: tell me the output of your **request.getParameter("cdate")**

Comment: 01/05/2016     this is output of my cdate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99773/discussion-between-manojrohit-and-nikhi-k-bansal).

Comment: you have to use

'**new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("cdate"))** ' this format to parse your date

Comment: At last I get solution for that  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        
    java.util.Date util_StartDate = format.parse( request.getParameter("cdate") );
    java.sql.Date sql_StartDate = new java.sql.Date( util_StartDate.getTime() );                                                                                            ps.setDate( 1, sql_StartDate );

Answer (score 0):

You should really be doing
`Date date = sdf.parse(ar);`
to reuse the earlier string.

To make this a bit smoother:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    String ar=request.getParameter("cdate"); 
    if(ar == null)
        ar = "";
    ar = ar.trim();
    if(request.getParameter("Submit")!=null) {
        PreparedStatement ps=null;
        Connection con=null;
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
            java.util.Date date = null;
            date = sdf.parse(ar);

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/form","root","");
            String q="insert into t1 values (?)";

            ps= (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(q);

            ps.setString(1,ar);

            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It would be very helpful if you listed any examples of the failure, but hopefully this fixes any issues you have.

Comment: still I get same error as I got earlier like "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "01/05/2016"  "     Can you explain me from code where I make mistake because I did as you said but still get prblm it means I am making mistake so explain me.